# Can't run shell script with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, shell, processbuilder

I adopted the code from one of the similar questions:

```
    Process p = null;
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("scr.sh");
    pb.directory(new File("/Users/alex/"));
    p = pb.start();
    Thread.sleep(TimeConst.SECOND);
```

And run this code from `public static main()`, I did place `scr.sh` file under `alex` folder but receive the exception: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory`

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try `./scr.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I removed a line that specified a working directory and replace file name with a absolute path instead and then it worked.

In order to receive `echo` messages I had to read from my stdin (?):

```
final Scanner in = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (in.hasNextLine())
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
        }).start();
```